# batch script which loops through files if they don't begin with {

Tags: windows, batch-file

I could use some help, I've tried similar topics but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

What I need is a batch script which loops through a directory searching for files of type `.pro` but don't begin with the character `{`.

The script then searches all the files and echoes the lines which are found between the numbers `574,` and `575,`.

I've got all the things done except when I try to check for file names I cant get it to work properly and it seems so simple.

My script looks like this:

```
@echo off

set "sPath=C:\Users\jspajic\Desktop\batskripte\test\test files" 
set "ispis=C:\Users\jspajic\Desktop\batskripte\test\Opera_procesi_DataTabovi.txt"

echo %sPath% > %ispis%

pushd %sPath%

for %%f in (*.pro) do (          :: ---> I guess this part needs to be altered

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=]" %%a in ('findstr /n /B "574," "%%f"') do (set s=%%a )

    if !s! neq 0 (

        for /f "delims=]" %%b in ('findstr /n /B "575," "%%f"') do (set kraj=%%b)
        if !kraj! neq 0 (

            @set /a "ss=s+1"
            @set /a "kraj=kraj+0"
            @set /a "s=s+0"

            if !ss! NEQ !kraj! (

                @echo:
                echo %%f



                @set /a "counter=1"
                for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('type "%%f" ^| findstr /n "^"') do (

                    if !counter! GTR !s! if !counter! LSS !kraj! echo.%%B

                    @set /a "counter=counter+1"
                )
            )   
        )

    )
endlocal

) >> %ispis%

popd
```

I tried with `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.pro^|findstr "[A-z]*\.pro" ')` 
or with similar ideas but I cant get it to work cause I just dont know batch scripts that well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for %%f in (*.pro) do ( set "dummy=%%f"
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 if "!dummy:~0,1!" neq "{" (
```

should solve your problem. Note that it adds an extra level of parentheses, so a matching `)` needs to be added after the `endlocal` but you seem to be adept at doing that.

Assign the filename to a dummy variable, then see whether the 1st character of that dummy is NOT equal to "{" before executing the rest of the code.

From the prompt, `set /?` will show documentation about substringing - you seem to have `delayed expansion` worked out.

Answer (score 2):

Because your character does not have a case, *(upper | lower)*, and your search directory is already current; this can be easily catered for using `EOL` in your `For` loop:

```dos
For /F "EOL={Delims=" %%f In ('Dir/B/A-D *.pro') Do (
```

Comment: might go wrong with filenames, that contain a `{` (but not as first character)

Comment: How, @Stephan ?

Comment: thank you for the comment. Unfortunately using this I get a message 
"EOL was unexpected at this time ... And It seems like it could be problematic if there are { elsewhere in the file name so I acepted the previous comment as the solution

Comment: uh? According to the helpfile, `eol` gives a "end of line comment character". Just tried it; obviously, the "end of line comment" means, "the line starts with...". Sorry, works as intended. (Note to myself: never ever trust the documentation unless you really tried it out)

Comment: No worries, @Stephan, the help should technically say Start/Beginning Of Line. Josip, it works, as confirmed by Stephan, your error message suggests to me that you've missed either the opening or closing double quotes around `"EOL={Delims="`. In your specific case my answer is more efficient that the other given answers.

Comment: @Compo sorry I tried it again and it worked. My bad. I wish I could accept both as answer... Thank you for the help, Im gonna go with the previous solution as I can easily change which character I do or dont want at the begining of my file name in the future.

Answer (score 1):

use `for /f` with `dir`, filtered by `findstr` (eliminate every token that starts with `{`):

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d *.pro^|findstr /vb "{"') do (
```